# open png file with adobeacrobat pro dc vba

Tags: excel, vba, acrobat

Last night I achieve to open png files with adobeacrobat pro dc and save them in pdf format. It works perfectly, I set a folder and it search on every folder and subfolder for png files and when it found someone it opens with acrobat and then saved it in pdf format. Today nothing works, moreover, the original code which only works on a single file doesn't works neither

```
Sub OpenHow()
Dim Acroapp As New Acrobat.Acroapp
Dim pddoc As New Acrobat.AcroPDDoc

    Set Acroapp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
    Set pddoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.pddoc")
    
    pddoc.Open ("C:/1.png")
    
    pddoc.Save PDSaveFull, "C:/1.pdf"
    
    Acroapp.Exit

            
End Sub
```

Any clue of what might have gone wrong?:S

Thanks in advance

Comment: Nothing changed between when it worked versus when it didn't? Is the file png always in that same location?

Comment: Nothing has changed, nobody can modify this file instead of me. Modifying this code I was able to generate like....10000 pdf files last night. It was quite messy at the begining because it only convert the files in the first subfolder it founds but I was able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I don't really know when or why I have deleted the avdoc object. Just in case someone will find it usefull here's the correct code

```
Sub OpenHow()
Dim avdoc As New Acrobat.AcroAVDoc
Dim Acroapp As New Acrobat.Acroapp
Dim pddoc As New Acrobat.AcroPDDoc

    Set Acroapp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
    Set avdoc = CreateObject("acroexch.avdoc")
    
    avdoc.Open "C:\1.png", ""
    Set pddoc = avdoc.GetPDDoc()
    
    pddoc.Save PDSaveFull, "C:\1.pdf"
    
    Acroapp.Exit
    Acroapp.CloseAllDocs
    Set Acroapp = Nothing
    Set avdoc = Nothing
    Set pddoc = Nothing    
            
End Sub
```

Hope somebody find it useful